# Crystal reports returning values like one looking for instead of equal

Tags: where-clause, selection, equals, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating a Report=>selectionFormulas=>Record, and then I have this:

```
({Facilities_ALL.Fac} IN ['S', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'SJ', 'F', 'N'])
AND
({Facilities_ALL.status} = "Active")
AND
isNull({Facilities_ALL.Department}) 
OR
isNull({Facilities_ALL.Section})
```

For some reason, it's returning both ones that are "Active" as well as ones that are "Inactive".  It looks correct to me as well as instructions I found online.  How do I fix it so it only returns "Active" ones?  What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed an extra set of parenthesis around the last 2 things:

```
({Facilities_ALL.Fac} IN ['S', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'SJ', 'F', 'N'])
AND
({Facilities_ALL.status}="Active")
AND
(
isNull({Facilities_ALL.Department}) 
OR
isNull({Facilities_ALL.Section})
)
```